# CSSStyleSheet type issue while trying to insert a css rule with typescript

Tags: css, typescript

I try to insert a css rule with typescript based on https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript. The method insertRule is not recognized. I have the following error:

> Type 'StyleSheet' is not assignable to type 'CSSStyleSheet'. Property 'cssRules' is missing in type 'StyleSheet'.

Here is my code:

```
let stylesheet: CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
stylesheet.insertRule(".scroll-content { overflow: hidden;}",0);
```

I'm working with ionic 2 and angular 2.

Comment: Replace `let stylesheet: CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];` with  `stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];`. By the way, what is `styleSheets`? Is it an array?

Comment: Check out my answer, should work for u ;9

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet for defining your stylesheet slightly modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24473183/4493079).

```
if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
    let stylesheet: CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0];
else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
    let stylesheet: CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to convert that var into a `CSSStyleSheet` , right after retrieving the current stylesheet.

This code will work for you:

```
let stylesheet= document.styleSheets[0];
(stylesheet as CSSStyleSheet).insertRule(".scroll-content { overflow: hidden;}",0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here from the future, I had a similar issue with Typescript and 'CSSStyleSheet':

> Property 'replaceSync' does not exist on type 'CSSStyleSheet'

Turns out the default Typescript interface was incomplete. I fixed it by adding my own like below, notice the last two rules which are missing on the default interface for some reason:

```
/* 
   declarations.d.ts
   Or wherever tsconfig.json is looking for .ts files in your project
*/

interface CSSStyleSheet {
  readonly cssRules: CSSRuleList
  readonly ownerRule: CSSRule | null
  readonly rules: CSSRuleList
  addRule(selector?: string, style?: string, index?: number): number
  deleteRule(index: number): void
  insertRule(rule: string, index?: number): number
  removeRule(index?: number): void
  replace(reset_style: string | CSSStyleSheet): Promise<void>
  replaceSync(reset_style: string | CSSStyleSheet): void
}
```